# How can I estimate a circle from a noisy image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to process images from a camera videostream. The camera is observing an electrode after a wire has been welded to it and my goal is to estimate the location of the center of the weld. I'm able to get a clear target by converting the image into HSV and thresholding hues from 6 to 20, however the resulting threshold is very noisy. You can clearly see circular features in the threshold image, however the components aren't connected so I'm having trouble getting a good approximation using HoughCircles. I've also tried using minEnclosingCircle on contours after sorting them by area but it's no more consistent and much slower.
I apologize for the poor quality, I'm new to coding and python is the only language I'm comfortable with.
I'm using Python 3.0 and OpenCV 4.3.0

[Image of what the camera sees...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f0pP.jpg)
[Image after thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XvrT.png)   [More Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBARq.jpg)

```
    frame_raw = cam.get_array()
    #frame_raw = np.load('frame_raw5.npy')#loads array directly instead of image
    frame_color = cv2.cvtColor(frame_raw,cv2.COLOR_BayerRG2RGB)#convert to color
    frame_down = cv2.pyrDown(frame_color)#scale down to speed up processing
    frame_blur = cv2.medianBlur(frame_down, int(2*values["-BLUR SLIDER-"]+1))
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_down,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame_down, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   
    frame_threshold = cv2.inRange(frame_HSV, (values["-LOW H-"], values["-LOW S-"], values["-LOW V-"]), (values["-HIGH H-"], values["-HIGH S-"], values["-HIGH V-"]))
    edges = cv2.Canny(frame_blur, values["-CANNY SLIDER A-"], values["-CANNY SLIDER B-"])
    #Try to find circles approximating weld----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try:
        #[ry1:ry2,rx1:rx2] is bounding box around the weld selected by cv2.ROI
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame_threshold[ry1:ry2,rx1:rx2],cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,1,param1=1,param2=20,minRadius=100,maxRadius=200)
    except:
        None
    try:
        if circles is not None:            
            weld = np.around(np.average(circles, axis=1)).flatten().astype(int)#average all circles into one
            if len(weld_list) > 15: weld_list.pop()#add average to list, past averages from 15 frames
            weld_list.insert(0,weld)
            if weld_list:
                weld_centroid = np.average(weld_list,axis=0).astype(int)
        if values["-CIRCLES-"]:
            cv2.circle(frame_down[ry1:ry2,rx1:rx2,:],(weld_centroid[0],weld_centroid[1]),weld_centroid[2],(100,255,100),2)
            cv2.circle(frame_down[ry1:ry2,rx1:rx2,:],(weld_centroid[0],weld_centroid[1]),5,(100,255,100),-1)
    except:
        None
```

Comment: Please add an image annotated to show where that circle is.